# How to extract only text from a document(it may be a pdf,word or any other) using apache tika?

Tags: apache, apache-tika

I am trying to extract only text from a pdf or word file that can contain images and other things as well using apache tika .How can I get only text from them?
What are the dependencies that i need in tika?
This the java code i have written:

package secondp;

```
           import java.io.File;
           import org.apache.tika.Tika;

           import java.io.File;
           import java.io.FileInputStream;
           import java.io.IOException;

           import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
           import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
           import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
           import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
           import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
           import org.apache.tika.Tika;

           import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

           public class trial {
               public static void main(final String[] args) {
                   try {
                       System.out.println(trial.convert("test.pdf"));
                   } catch (final Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }

               public static String convert(final String fileName) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
                   try(final FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName))) {
                       final BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
                       new PDFParser().parse(inputstream, handler, new Metadata(), new ParseContext());
                       return handler.toString().trim();
                   }
               }
           }
```

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? Tika App? Tika Server? Java, and if so, with what code?

Comment: With java and apache tika library that is available and I am trying it in eclipse IDE...and I'm able to get contents from pdf that containing only text but not from a pdf with images.It would be great if I am able to get text from pdf with images..

Comment: You need to post the code we're using, we can't see what you're doing wrong without it!